Input empty but .tfrecord has data, so it doesnt get loaded into training model
I am trying to train an object detection model using my own dataset in google colab using the tensorflow object detection API. However, I keep getting this error message when i attempt to train my model.
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input is empty.
[[{{function_node case_cond_cond_jpeg_false_220}}{{node case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
[[MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard]]
[[RemoteCall]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
I think this is an error with the .tfrecord file but ive checked them and they all have decoded data. Can someone help me fix this error. I can't attatch the tf record files but is there anything I can do to make sure the data is the right format?
I made a script to convert csv and png data into a tfrecord. this made a tfrecord but apparently its not working on the model.
